# creating flatlist grid from api data

Tags: css, react-native, grid, react-native-flatlist

I want to create a dynamic grid in the flatlist, but it is not dynamic when data increases, my data is an array of object which has images and other information too.

I am using

```
columnWrapperStyle={{flexWrap: 'wrap', flex: 1 / 2}}

width: "100%",
height: height / 2.3,
```

I want to create something like this
[image]

if there is one image the grid should cover full width and if two images it should take half of width,

now the main issue I want to do something when there are three images the first height should be full and others will divide the height in half, same for the last one.

thanks.

Comment: read this: https://css-tricks.com/exploring-css-grids-implicit-grid-and-auto-placement-powers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use or get inspired by this package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fb-image-grid

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import FbGrid from "react-native-fb-image-grid";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.inner_container}>
          <FbGrid
            images={[
              "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png",
            ]}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.inner_container}>
          <FbGrid
            images={[
              "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png",
              "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png",
            ]}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.inner_container}>
          <FbGrid
            images={[
              "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png",
              "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png",
              "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png",
            ]}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.inner_container}>
          <FbGrid
            images={[
              "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png",
              "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png",
              "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png",
              "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png",
              "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png",
              "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/assets/favicon.png",
            ]}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#eee",
  },
  inner_container: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "20%",
  },
});

export default App;
```

Live Demo - https://snack.expo.dev/@emmbyiringiro/c182c6

Comment: thank you for this package but this package only supports images, my data also includes other information which I need to show on top of images.

Comment: I updated my question, sorry for miscommunication.

Comment: As I mentioned, this package will not resolve all your edge cases. Use it as a reference for grid layout positioning and resizing as per item count then replace the image component with your own  implementation - https://github.com/jibraniqbal666/react-native-fb-image-grid/blob/master/src/fb_grid/fb_grid.js#L10

Comment: Cool. Glad you figured out?